# error while trying to put values into an array using jquery each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have this code:

```
$(".categoty-add").each(function(i) {
            categories[i][0] = $(this).val();
    });
```

And in output i get

```
TypeError: can't convert undefined to object    
categories[i][0] = $(this).val();
```

This is my array:

```
    var categories = new Array(2);
    for (i = 0; i < categories . length; ++ i)
    categories [i] = new Array (2);
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What type of elements are those identified by the class `categoty-add`? Do they have a value attribute (for ex: input)?

Comment: value from texbox, and somethig is wrong with iterator, becouse if I replace i in categories[i][0] to f.ex 1 it's working

Comment: you are not checking if categories array has i index or not , are you sure that the length of categories array is equal or greater than the number of your .categoty-add items ?

Comment: You probably have more elements than arrays.

Answer (score 0):

There has to be two textbox with class `category-add`. it they are more than two then you iterator i will be assigned a value >= 2 and then you statement becomes

```
categories[2][0] = $(this).val();
```

which is out of the bounds of the array.

Comment: There are 2 textbox with this class

Comment: @user1776165 : if none of these three answers satisfy your need , just leave a comment , and if any of these is a correct answer , don't walk away after getting the answer, back and mark it as answer .

Comment: Use alert to check the value of "$(this).val()". It may be returning undefined.

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically create an array ( first time code is run), and later update it you can do this:

```
/* create empty array, syntax is shortcut for new Array() and just as efficient*/
var categories=[];

$(".categoty-add").each(function(i) {
   if( categories[i] ){ /* if doesn't exist will be undefined and trigger "else"*/
        /* sub array exists, just update it*/
        categories[i][0] = $(this).val();
    }else{ 
        /* create new sub array and give value to first position */
        categories[i] =[ $(this).val()];
    }
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/FFQ2s/